# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object] due to middleware

Tags: object, new-operator, throw

I add some middlewares in route and got this error :

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const isAuthenticated = require("../Middleware/auth.js");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/:prodeuctId", isAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
 // code ...
});
```

Error is following :

```
       throw new Error(msg);
    ^
```

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
at Route. [as get] (C:\Users\Nayab\Desktop\AxxoCare\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211:15)
at proto. [as get] (C:\Users\Nayab\Desktop\AxxoCare\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:521:19)
at Object. (C:\Users\Nayab\Desktop\AxxoCare\backend\Controllers\userController.js:291:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Nayab\Desktop\AxxoCare\backend\App.js:3:14)